# Distinguishing between libraries? (Directory structure)

Tags: php, oop, web-applications, directory-structure

So, here's a quick extract of the directory structure on a web application that I am working on currently:

```
/app
  /libraries
    User_Input.php
    Database.php
    InvoiceHandler.php
```

Do you think that the `InvoiceHandler` is a bit odd in this collection? I sure do.

Until recently, I have ignored the need to distinguish between de-facto libraries that actually are the middle-layer between my application and other services  (such as a Persistent storage) and the classes of code that I have written myself that contains custom logic for my application (such as the Invoice_Handler in this case).

But as my application grows, this creates more and more of a mess. I haven't seen any good examples on this as of today and I have not enough experience to come to a conclusion by myself:

**What does conventions and common sense say on separation of these two definite and so clearly different sort of classes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up separating my libraries depending on what level of abstraction they contained. In search of a better name of high-level abstraction, I used the category name `services` for these and retained with `libraries` for low-level abstraction classes.

Ie. :

```
/common
    /libraries (low-level)
        database.php
        session.php
        email.php
    /services (high-level)
        auth.php (dependent on database + session)
        invoicing.php (dependent on database + email)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structure:

```
libs
    Common(Core)
        Db
          Connection(Database).php
    Input
         Validator
         Filter
    Handler(Controller)
        Invoice.php
    Model
```

Comment: Hi! Maybe I wasn't clear. The app is already MVC-based, so the `Invoice_Handler` in my example wasn't a controller, but a library that actually takes care of different Invoice-related operations and thereby are dependent on the `Database` & `Email` classes, for instance. How do I separate those three from eachother to ensure less confusion?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague, and the example filenames shown don't really explain much about them. I will however say that you need to group your classes together into a structure that makes sense.

```
/app
  /library
    /My
      /Controller
        AbstractController.php
      /Filter
        CamelCaseToUnderscore.php
        UnderscoreToCamelCase.php
      /Validator
        Date.php
        Url.php
```

The classes I've used are vastly different (at least I think they are) from yours, but you can clearly see they are grouped into a logical structure.